# Using bootstrap ccs to markup a databined select

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angularJs application that I'm trying to look nice with Bootstrap CSS.

I had:

```
<select name="mode" 
    ng-model="module.mode" 
    ng-options="m for m in modes" 
    ng-change="onModeChanged()"></select>
```

This ended up as:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" id="modeDropDownMenu">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby=="modeDropDownMenu">
    <li ng-repeat="m in modes">
       <a href="#" ng-click="onModeChanged()">{{m}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I lost my model `ng-model="module.mode"` in the process :-(

Where do I have to apply this? Nothing I already tried seems to work.

Comment: What exactly is the "process" ?

Comment: the "process" is changing the code from as-is to to-be.

Comment: Can't you just update your 'model.mode' from within onModeChanged()?

Comment: Nope, the ''onModeChanged()' triggers additional actions after the mode has been changed. I want no code changes, just another markup. Since css was invented to separate markup from behavior this should not be a big thing, I assumed.

Comment: Listen to @ChrisHermut: do just update your `model.mode` from within `onModeChanged()`, I think this is **the** solution: `ngRepeat` is a different beast from `select`...

Comment: o well... Just added an changeMode(m) function. and called the onChanged from within. Can live with it. Sometimes someone just have to say 'Listen to..' :-)